# RAILS : PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create extension "pgcrypto" HINT: Must be superuser to create this extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am taking over a project started by a developer two years ago.
I can't start the migrations I get the error message below:

**"An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied to create extension "pgcrypto"
HINT: Must be superuser to create this extension."**

I tried to enter the command lines to create a psql super-user but it's doesn't work :

```
$ psql -U postgres 
postgres=# ALTER USER username CREATEDB;
```

My development DB looks like :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I was provided with a db production snapshot.

Could you help us with this configuration?
I used SQLite3 before and i'm totally lost now!
Should i need to use AWS rds to setup db ?

Comment: at a quick glance, I'd suspect that it's telling you what to do.  connect into your postgres as an admin user and run `create extension "pgcrypto"` and see if you can then run the deployment?

Comment: dear jad, I can't connect to the development database from the snapshot. (maybe i don't have the right command line and configuration knowledge)
when I launch my puma server and I run the migrations I come across the error quoted above

Comment: it doesn't matter where you get access from, you'll need to get access to the database as an "administrator" in order to run the command on the database.  I believe you'll probably find the command in the migration files, and the previous developer always connected into the database as an administrative user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found the solution this morning :

1- sudo -u postgres psql // connect to postgresql 
2- password = **** // adding your password 
3- postgres=# \du  //list of user 
4- postgres=# CREATE ROLE username LOGIN SUPERUSER 'password'; //create superuser 
5- postgres=# ALTER USER username WITH SUPERUSER; // Edit user role to superuser 
6- migrate 

and it works fine